# plotting two dataframes at the same time in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I would like to plot the values Emean against T (like shown in the image below). 
My guess is that there should be only two lines, since there are only two dataframes. 
This means that the "connecting" line that I marked in yellow should not be there. Is there a way to "separate" the plots?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to plot two lines as they are defined by grouping variable `:L`. If this is correct then you can do the following:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> using Plots

julia> using StatsPlots

julia> df = DataFrame(L=[1,1,1,2,2,2], T=[1,2,3,1,2,3], Emean=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ L      T      Emean
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      1      1
   2 │     1      2      2
   3 │     1      3      3
   4 │     2      1      4
   5 │     2      2      5
   6 │     2      3      6

julia> @df df plot(:T, :Emean, group=:L)
```

to get what you want.

Here I am using the functionality provided by the [StatsPlots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl) package.